# Android EditText event listeners

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using `onTextChanged()` for `EditText` and `onKey()` event handler. I want to handle `onTextChanged()` when text is entered and `onKey()` when text is deleted i.e. i want to handle the `KEYCODE_DEL`. But my `onTextchanged()` event always fires. Anyone can post me some ideas.

```
ed.setOnKeyListener(this); 
ed. addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   //
});
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {    
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEY CODE_ENTER) {
// 
});
```

Comment: Have you called `ed.setOnKeyListener(this);`?

Comment: Did you mean `onKey` and not `Key`?

Comment: yes I am calling onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event), to handle the keyboard delete key and ed.setOnKeyListener(this);
In my samsung device, the onKey() event is called first where i set text to the edittext which calls the ontextchanged(). but in my nexus device the ontextChanged() calls first and the onKey() is not firing

Comment: sorry trevor-e, i edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue by writing the whole logic inside the TextWatcher() using all of its callbacks as onKeyListener will not be fired for SoftKeyBoard for Nexus Devices.
I am posting the code which may be helpful for others

```
    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                private String previousDigits, num;
                private boolean textChanged = false;

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence currentDigits, int start,
                        int before, int count) {
                    if (!(previousDigits.equalsIgnoreCase(currentDigits.toString()))) {
                        textChanged = true;
                        num = getStrippedNumber(currentDigits
                                .toString());
                                            //getStrippedNumber method is used for getting the numeric digits from the string.
                        if (num.length() > 6) {
                            num = ("(" + num.substring(0, 3) + ") "
                                    + num.substring(3, 6) + "-" + num.substring(6));
                        } else if (num.length() > 3) {
                            num = ("(" + num.substring(0, 3) + ") " + num
                                    .substring(3));
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    previousDigits = s.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (textChanged) {
                        textChanged = false;
                        mEditPhoneNo.setText(num);
                        mEditPhoneNo.setSelection(mEditPhoneNo.getText().length());
                    }
                }
            });

    Thanks Guyz
```